# Derby-Bitronix-Camel. Cannot commit a resource enlisted in a global transaction

Tags: java, transition

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    Configuration BTMconfig = TransactionManagerServices.getConfiguration();
    BTMconfig.setServerId("spring-btm");
    BitronixTransactionManager BitronixTM =  TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager();

    JtaTransactionManager JTAtm = new JtaTransactionManager();
    JTAtm.setUserTransaction(BitronixTM);
    JTAtm.setTransactionManager(BitronixTM);

    PoolingDataSource xaDataSource = new PoolingDataSource();

    xaDataSource.setClassName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedXADataSource");
    xaDataSource.setUniqueName("xaDataSource");
   xaDataSource.setMinPoolSize(1);
   xaDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(5);
    xaDataSource.setAllowLocalTransactions(true);

    Properties xaDataSourceProp = new Properties();
    xaDataSourceProp.put("DatabaseName","DerbyDB");
    xaDataSourceProp.put("CreateDatabase","true");
    xaDataSourceProp.put("DataSourceName","xaDataSource");

    xaDataSource.setDriverProperties(xaDataSourceProp);

    xaDataSource.init();

    SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
    registry.put("transactionManager", JTAtm);
    registry.put("xaDataSource", xaDataSource);

    CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);


    camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder(){

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("file:data/inbox?noop=true").
            transacted().
            process(new ToJdbcProcessor()).
            to("jdbc:xaDataSource");
        }
    });

    camelContext.start();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

}
```

Не желает выполнять транзакцию. В лог выводит следующее:

```
[ thread #0 - file://data/inbox] JdbcProducer                   WARN  Error occurred during jdbc rollback. This exception will be ignored.
java.sql.SQLException: cannot rollback a resource enlisted in a global transaction
    at bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.JdbcConnectionHandle.rollback(JdbcConnectionHandle.java:120)[btm-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_111]
    at bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.BaseProxyHandlerClass.invoke(BaseProxyHandlerClass.java:64)[btm-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.rollback(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jdbc.JdbcProducer.processingSqlBySettingAutoCommit(JdbcProducer.java:92)[camel-jdbc-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jdbc.JdbcProducer.process(JdbcProducer.java:67)[camel-jdbc-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:400)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:172)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processByErrorHandler(TransactionErrorHandler.java:220)[camel-spring-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:101)[camel-spring-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:114)[camel-spring-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processByErrorHandler(TransactionErrorHandler.java:220)[camel-spring-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler$1.doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionErrorHandler.java:183)[camel-spring-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:34)[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.doInTransactionTemplate(TransactionErrorHandler.java:176)[camel-spring-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processInTransaction(TransactionErrorHandler.java:136)[camel-spring-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:105)[camel-spring-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:114)[camel-spring-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:460)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:227)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:191)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)[:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)[:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)[:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)[:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_111]
[ thread #0 - file://data/inbox] DefaultErrorHandler            ERROR Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-office11238-50617-1479470669103-0-3 on ExchangeId: ID-office11238-50617-1479470669103-0-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.sql.SQLException: cannot commit a resource enlisted in a global transaction

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [file://data/inbox?noop=true                                                   ] [       211]
[route1            ] [transacted1       ] [transacted                                                                    ] [       208]
[route1            ] [process1          ] [Processor@0x39502c11                                                          ] [         1]
[route1            ] [to1               ] [jdbc:xaDataSource                                                             ] [       182]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.sql.SQLException: cannot commit a resource enlisted in a global transaction
    at bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.JdbcConnectionHandle.commit(JdbcConnectionHandle.java:111)[btm-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_111]
    at bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.BaseProxyHandlerClass.invoke(BaseProxyHandlerClass.java:64)[btm-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.commit(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jdbc.JdbcProducer.processingSqlBySettingAutoCommit(JdbcProducer.java:88)[camel-jdbc-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jdbc.JdbcProducer.process(JdbcProducer.java:67)[camel-jdbc-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:400)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:172)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processByErrorHandler(TransactionErrorHandler.java:220)[camel-spring-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:101)[camel-spring-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:114)[camel-spring-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processByErrorHandler(TransactionErrorHandler.java:220)[camel-spring-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler$1.doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionErrorHandler.java:183)[camel-spring-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:34)[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.doInTransactionTemplate(TransactionErrorHandler.java:176)[camel-spring-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processInTransaction(TransactionErrorHandler.java:136)[camel-spring-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:105)[camel-spring-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:114)[camel-spring-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:460)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:227)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:191)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)[:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)[:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)[:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)[:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_111]
[ thread #0 - file://data/inbox] TransactionErrorHandler        WARN  Transaction rollback (0x5bc9ba1d) redelivered(unknown) for (MessageId: ID-office11238-50617-1479470669103-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-office11238-50617-1479470669103-0-2) caught: java.sql.SQLException: cannot commit a resource enlisted in a global transaction
[ thread #0 - file://data/inbox] GenericFileOnCompletion        WARN  Rollback file strategy: org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy@11388081 for file: GenericFile[1.txt]
[ thread #0 - file://data/inbox] JdbcProducer                   WARN  Error occurred during jdbc rollback. This exception will be ignored.
```

А-а-а-а! Спасите-помогите.

Comment: база не залочена ?

Comment: Никак нет. После этого подключался к базе через этот-же самый xaDataSouce. Запрос выполняется нормально.  Connection connection = xaDataSource.getConnection();
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TEXTMSGS");
        while (rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println("RESULT DB:"+  rs.getInt("ID")+ " " + rs.getString("BODY"));
        }

Comment: возможно, вот тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279120/get-error-cannot-commit-a-resource-enlisted-in-a-global-transaction-in-activemq имеется ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Разобрался. Надо было установить свойство xaDataSource.setAutomaticEnlistingEnabled(false);
При конфигурировании через spring:
<property name="AutomaticEnlistingEnabled" value="false"/>